# how to change json provider limit in vba excel

Tags: json, excel, url, response, limit

The API provider has set a limit of 20 records in json. For example I have 415 records. Would there be any way to circumvent this limit and search for all records?

`{"offset":0,**"limit":20**,"total"415,"`

```vb
Private Function GetResponse(ByVal url As String) As String
    Const RunAsync As Boolean = True
    Const ProcessComplete As Integer = 4

    Sheets("getLayer").Select

    'Limpa área que irá receber os dados

    Worksheets("getLayer").Range("A1:C1000").ClearContents

    Dim request As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set request = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    
    Dim response, result As String
    Dim procura As Variant
    
    With request
    
    .Open "GET", url, RunAsync
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application-json"
    .send
    
    Do While request.readyState <> ProcessComplete
    DoEvents
    Loop
    
    response = .responseText
    
    Set request = Nothing
    
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: It would depend on the API.   What API is it?  Can you specify the response size?  Can you specify the offset?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need the code to generate the total of 415 json, but it's limiting it to 20 json. Is there any possibility to run all

Comment: hello @StephenOstermiller the answer always comes only 20 json